# Create pandas columns from json pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
d = {'parameters': [{'Year': '2018',
 'Median Age': 'nan',
 'Total Non-Family Household Income': 289.0,
 'Total Household Income': 719.0,
 'Gini Index of Income Inequality': 0.4121}]}
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_sample.head()
```

I want to convert that json into pandas columns. How do I do this? Assume I only have the dataframe not the parameter `d`

I saw this example

```
#which columns have json
#device
json_cols = ['device', 'geoNetwork', 'totals',  'trafficSource']

for column in json_cols:

    c_load = test[column].apply(json.loads)
    c_list = list(c_load)
    c_dat = json.dumps(c_list)

    test = test.join(pd.read_json(c_dat))
    test = test.drop(column , axis=1)
```

But this does not seem too pythonic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```py
df_sample = pd.json_normalize(data=d, record_path=['parameters'])
```

Resulting dataframe:

| Year | Median Age | Total Non-Family Household Income | Total Household Income | Gini Index of Income Inequality |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | nan | 289.0 | 719.0 | 0.4121 |

**UPD**:

If you already have dataframe loaded, then applying `pd.Series` should work:

```py
df_sample = df_sample['parameters'].apply(pd.Series) # or df_sample['parameters'].map(json.loads).apply(pd.Series) if data is not already dict
```

Comment: Assume, I do not have the parameter d, what do I do then?